# os.walk() not processing subdirectories when using UNC paths

Tags: python, windows, os.walk

I'm having trouble with `os.walk()` in python 2.7.8 on Windows.

When I supply it with a 'normal' path such as `"D:\Test\master"` it works as expected. However when I supply it with a UNC path such as `"\\?\D:\Test\master"` it will report the root directory as expected but it will not drill down into the sub directories, nor will it raise an exception.

My research: I read on the [help page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) that `os.walk()` accepts a function argument to handle errors. By default this argument is `None` so no error is reported.

I passed a simple function to print the error and received the following for every directory.

```
def WalkError(Error):
    raise Exception(Error)
```

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Compare.py", line 988, in StartServer
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOT_DIR,True,WalkError):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.8\lib\os.py", line 296, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.8\lib\os.py", line 281, in walk
    onerror(err)
  File "Compare.py", line 62, in WalkError
    raise Exception(Error)
Exception: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '\\\\?\\D:\\Test\\master\\localization/*.*'
```

Comment: You can actually post an answer to your own question. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: The ``\\?\`` prefix isn't a UNC path. A UNC path such as `\\server\share` becomes `\\?\UNC\server\share` using the extended path prefix. This ``\\?\`` prefix bypasses normal path processing. Windows simply replaces it with the NT DOS devices prefix ``\??\``, which has the object manager search for the device in the logon session DOS devices and then the `\Global??` object directory. This means a ``\\?\`` path must be a `unicode` string, since NT paths are Unicode, and must use only backslash as the path separator since a forward slash is just a regular name character in the NT namespace.

Comment: If you use `'//?/D:/Test/master'`, it does not bypass regular path processing and the path is limited to `MAX_PATH` (260) characters. Use `u'\\\\?\\D:\\Test\\master'`.

Comment: @eryksun - This is the correct solution. My code is all in unicode, so I assumed that wasn't the issue, but it transmits path names over a socket and therefore the unicode 'format' is lost. The receiving end takes the bytes from the socket and puts them into a string of the default encoding. I take that string and use it as top to walk a directory and it fails. Converting to unicode and running the walk makes it work perfectly. - Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from the original author (originally posted as an edit to the question):

Instant update: In the process of inspecting `\lib\os.py`, I discovered the error stems from `os.listdir()`. I searched for the above error message in relation to `os.listdir()` and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051646/5286388) which worked for me.

It looks like if you're going to use UNC style paths with `os.` modules they need to Unixised (have their `\` converted to `/`). `\\\\?\\D:\\Test\\master\\` becomes `//?/D:/Test/master/` (note: you no longer need to escape the `\` which is handy).

This runs counter to the [UNC 'spec'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx) so be aware if you're working with other modules which respect Microsoft's UNC implementation.

(Sorry for the self-solution, I was going to close the tab but felt there was knowledge here which couldn't be found elsewhere.)

Comment: No such problem exists for UNC paths, and the ``\\?\`` prefix is not even a UNC path. You can't use slash as a path separator in an NT path, which Python violates by appending `/*.*` in the 8-bit `str` branch. If it appended `\*.*` you'd be able to use ``\\?\`` in a path that's not a `unicode` string, but it's only documented to allow up to 260 characters since older versions of Windows decode 8-bit ANSI strings to a statically allocated buffer that imposes this limit. Anyway, the 8-bit string branch of Python's `listdir` uses a stack allocated buffer that's also limited to 260 characters.

Comment: @eryksun I don't manage this answer, I don't take credit for it, I didn't write this. It was marked for deletion in the review queue, and it seemed to have helped the OP, so I merely salvaged it. Feel free to edit it, or even better - post your own answer. If you do so, please notify me so that I can delete this one. Thanks! :)

Comment: I have related answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36237176/205580) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24064783/205580). I could add another answer to discuss using ``\\?\`` with `listdir` in Python 2, but problems only come up when you try to use it with an 8-bit `str` path, which should be deprecated even in 2.7, just like `bytes` paths are deprecated for Windows in Python 3.