# get a List of files using UNC path on windows

Tags: python

I am trying to use Python 3 to list folders located on a Windows share drive.   I have mounted the share in Windows explorer and I can clearly see the files exists

I am using the following code:

```
path = r'//UNCpath/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    print(root, dirs)
print('Hello')
```

but in the debugger, when I step over the for loop, it goes straight to the print('Hello') as if os.walk not finding anything.   I don't get any error messages.

please let me know what I am missing, or if creds are needed.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705257/os-walk-not-processing-subdirectories-when-using-unc-paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error, what you said is correct, it is not finding the path, the code below is what I made as a semi project that works and is in correlation to yours:
I made it as an input function so you can find a specific file/folder

```
s = input("Enter the directory you wish to visit")
rootdi = rootdir+"\\"
root = rootdi+s
print(root)
if os.path.isfile(root) is False:
    print("No such directory")
    quit()
```

Comment: Make sure your adding your drive as that is missing from your question, aka c drive or h drive.

Comment: That's good some times my code will not work on another computer, happy to help